# How we can add the request parameter in with url in swagger tool

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I want to customize the input text box in swagger ui and test the rest service ,but while sending the request parameter in input text box the request parameter is not appended with service ulr ,
for example 
`curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8765/COMMONAPI/V2.0/gameList'` the piece of request param is not added and due to this I am getting null pointer exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd4fJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwsC9.png)

I want exact request as below

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8765/COMMONAPI/V2.0/gameList" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"timeStamp\": \"2019-03-18T05:11:15\", \"hashKey\": \"c0849bbf6eb17e48a72b92aa8f67650f\", \"apiKey\": \"72uyhsu87sf3\", \"apiId\": 6, \"sessionKey\": \"SdPpZI4LFTlux\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In you SwaggerConfiguration you can define `globalOperationParameters` for passing paramaters. Something like below.

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .globalOperationParameters(Arrays.asList(new ParameterBuilder()
                  .name("token")
                  .description("Authentication token obtained after authentication.")
                  .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                  .parameterType("header")
                  .required(true)
                  .build()))
          .select()

          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mypackage"))
        .build();
```

}